# C# - "Access Denied" for App Data

Tags: c#

I have written a application with C#.But,I continually get an error message of "access denied" for "App Data" under my user profile (password protected user account).BTW,I'm using Win7.

Here is my code:

```
string path = string.Concat(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "//Programım//");
```

Comment: Since we can't assume the obvious, `path` does exist when you put a breakpoint on this line and navigate to that path manually, right?

Comment: use `System.IO.Path.Combine`.

Comment: From what operation are you getting this? That 'I' looks funny, what culture is the app/OS using?

Comment: Side note: "//Programım//" is not valid path/portion of a path. You either want "\\Programım\\" or @"\Programım\".

Comment: @leppie-I'm getting in the delete operation.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: If you knew better, you would realize it makes absolutely no difference...

Comment: @Selo: Are you trying to delete that directory with `File.Delete`? Please provide more info.

Comment: @Selo, if you are using File.Delete, it won't work for a directory. It will also throw "access denied" if the file is read-only. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`System.IO.Path.Combine(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) instead of `string.Conact(...)` in this situation.  Like this...

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Programım");
```

The result of `path` in your original code might not be what you are actually expecting.

Once you are sure your `path` value is correct then call [`System.IO.Directory.Delete(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) like...

```
Directory.Delete(path, true);
```

If that still is not working, then there may be some other security permission problems with files in that directory, or with the directory itself.  See the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) for all of the exceptions that can be thrown from the `Delete` method and the reasons why.