# How to save and load an XML file in AppData?

Tags: c#, appdata

I've been teaching myself how to code lately because I am bored. I am trying to load an XML file on startup and put the contents of that file into a listbox, then save the contents of the listbox to the file on close. That's exactly what I have now. However I want to be able to load from AppData as well as save back to the AppData folder without having to type the full path. I've tried using "%AppData%/Roaming/MyApp/data.xml" but that does not work and throws a exception.

Here is what I have now:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("data.xml");
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            while (line != null) {
                Streamers.Items.Add(line);
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            Streamers.DataSource = line;
            Streamers.Sorted = true;
            sr.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GetFolderPath`

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Also you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/867493/2263683) for more information.

**Update**

Notice that you need Administrator rights to access this folder.

For `Access denied` error check these two answers:

[Number one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13107447/2263683)

> The directory `%AppData%` is a system-protected directory. Windows
>   will try to block any access to this directory as soon as the access
>   was not authorized (An access from another user than the
>   Administrator).

[Number two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273861/c-sharp-access-denied-for-app-data)

> I would use `System.IO.Path.Combine(...)` instead of
>   `string.Conact(...)` in this situation.  Like this...
>
> ```
> string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
> "Programım");
> ```

Comment: I managed to create a folder however I cannot save the XML there. I get an access is denied exception.

Comment: Alright. I managed to write to the AppData folder. Much thanks. Now how do I read from there? Beforehand, I just used StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("data.xml"); which only just read the locally found one and not the one in appdata

Comment: @JarrettMitchell try `string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData); StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path+"\\data.xml");`